# Setting Rules in Configuration of Comodo Personal Firewall

Tags: comodo-firewall

I come from Agnitum Outpost Firewall. I kept it until I could, but unfortunately the time to change is arrived.

I am referring to a personal leisure computer, with Windows 7 64. Nothing fancy, simple games, movies, ebooks, browsing cat videos.

The rule is simple, or at least I thought: nothing, literally nothing, connects to the net without manual approval. Video players for various formats do not need it. No program needs the abhorring "check new versions automatically at startup". The browser can get out only on port 80, other ports are to be approved case by case. Windows Update is done manually thru download of the patches when I decide.

And Outpost was the ideal in this (of course there were other good things, like protect the registry, block invading other processes memory space but I digress).

I want something free, just the basic stuff. NO antivirus, NO web filter, NO spam check and other things I manage elsewhere. Just check who wants send things outside the computer.

Now I am trying Comodo Personal Firewall, just to checking alternatives. The first impression is it does something good, but is very messy, but probably it is matter of getting habitued.

Primarily I would know how to set the "Firewall Rules" and the "HIPS Rules". They seem to be overlapping. Deleting everything from those rulesets, nothing should go out. But instead, everything can go out without warning. What should I set as a starting point so the connection is forbidden for every program?

After that, I would any program trying to connect to the internet raises a warning. This does not happen. But no, worse, I see a warning one time every 100 tries. The rule about the program sometimes is added to the "Firewall Rules" section, sometimes in the "HIPS section", but never in both. Probably so they do not feel neglected.

Well, if I delete the new created rule, that same program should raise again a warning right? Wrong, it goes out without permission and without rules. As i said, only if I click around close and reopen the program dozens of times, if I am lucky I got asked again.

I tried changing "Training Mode" into "Ruleset Mode" but nothing noticeable changed.

So, is there some order in this chaos? What exactly should I look to have iron rules, valid every time? Am I ignoring some little check box somewhere?

(or should I abandon this program? for what?)

I hope this post is clear enough, it reflects my confusion.

Comment: I lost interest in this question way before half way through. Please remove any extrenuous information (phrases such as "as usual, it's the best that dies sooner" don't add anything to the question. You will get a better response this way.

Comment: Comodo should not prompt again unless the program has changed (updated for example).

Comment: @Darren I removed the line you didn't like. I hope this will help.

Comment: @Proteus, it wasn't a single line that is an issue (and it's not that I didn't like it), just - bluntly - get to the point (or tl;dr).

Comment: @DavidPostill Obviously. The matter is there seems no way to set those rules to ask the first time in a consistent way.

Comment: @Darren Probably not even I by myself know what is the point, the program continues to act in an seemingly random way.

Comment: @Proteus, I think you are missing my point. I think your whole question can be summarized as "In Commodo firewall, how can I achieve X". You don't need all the other cruft that makes it hard and time consuming to read.

Comment: @Darren Actually I thought of posting such a wide question, but I thought it was too wide, and that it showed lack of effort. I thought it was better have more small questions, in the hope statistically at least some would get an answer. The nodal question is in the 3rd paragraph I guess.

Comment: @Proteus Set safe mode and allow or deny when asked.